# synchronise Microsoft Access database with Silverstripe website database

Tags: php, mysql, database, ms-access, silverstripe

My client has got an existing site with membership details, member portfolios and directories which are largely done manually in php associated with Silverstripe CMS platform which works well. Also their admin person has got an offline member data system - Microsoft Access, and they have been double adding membership details to MS Access according to the membership details on the website.

My first thought was to ditch the MS Access and keep all database online, but they have been working on MS Access for years even before the site was built, so we are thinking of keeping the MS Access as well as the site database.

This is the first time I am experiencing MS Access, and both database structures are set up differently. I am just wondering is it possible to synchronise MS Access and the website database? Eg the MS Access member data gets automatically updated when the membership is updated online.

How would I achieve it? Which programming languages would be used? Any secuirity issues to synchronise an offline MS Access and online website? Any steps, links or learning links would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: It is suggested to use MSSQL / MySQL instead of MS Access, as the latter one is more suitable for offline access.

Comment: Hi Raptor, thanks for you reply. sorry I'm not sure what you meant, can you explain a bit in details or examples. There are a website database and an offline MS Access database, is there any way to sunchronize the both together?

Comment: Are you able to create an ODBC connection from Access to the website database?

Comment: @grumpypanda in short, MS Access is not fast enough and does not support a lot of database features. Not recommended for website usage.

Comment: Hi HansUp, I'm not sure at this stage, I only just knew this MS Access, and I haven't done anything with it yet, so I thought I'd ask directions before I jump into the dark. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Raptor, I probably didn't make it clear sorry. I'm not going to use MS Access to be the website database, as I know the website database is set up pretty well already, because the admin person is used to use MS Access, I'm just wondering is there any way to update the MS Access automatically when the website membership data is updated online, or goes the other way, in another word to synchronise both. Or shall I go back to my first thought to give up on Access and just keep the website, I will need some suggestions from you guys to convice the client. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to use the `CsvBulkLoader` class, export regularly the Access db and importing it into SilverStripe via a custom CsvBulkLoader.
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/howto/csv-import

Or create a custom `BuildTask` that fetches the Access database and update SS with the new data. This would probably give you the most flexibility and this can be run as a CRON job so you don't have to do it manually.
http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-BuildTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:
Create a web service on the web site that returns the membership data. Create a script that calls that web service then updates the local MS Access database.

Comment: Hi Tarik, thanks for you reply. What kind of web service and script are you referring? I think both website membership database and MS Access membership database structured differently. Can you please give me more detailed explainations or examples? Thank you.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes. As for the script you can use vbscript or VBA within Access.

Comment: I'll need to look into this, I'm not familiar with Access so feeling a bit in the dark. With this vbscript, is there any way we can use php or javascript instead? Would you think this is possible to synchronize both website and offline Access? Eg update Access automatically when the membership is updated online. Any security issues? Thank you!

Comment: You can control access to the web service as you would do to any web page. As for the Access database, you can either use VB or actually any language of your choice to update it.